# Polymorphic LINQ Query

Tags: c#, linq

Having a bit of a problem getting my LINQ query to return the object type I want to work with. I'm pretty close just need a little bit of input.

I have five tables, Objects, People, Locations, Collections, and CollectionEntries.

Object is the base class for People, Locations, and Collections. A Collection has many CollectionEntries which may contain entries to People, Locations, and Collections.

Given a specific collection I want to write the LINQ query to retreive the People in that collection.

So far I have this, which returns me a list of CollectionEntries ( they correspond to the  People entries, yay half way! ) but I would rather have it return the instances of the People.

```
var people = collection.CollectionEntries.Where( 
  entry => entry.Object is Person ).ToList();
```

I have tried doing this:

```
var people = collection.CollectionEntries.Where( 
  entry => entry.Object is Person ).OfType<Person>().ToList();
```

but it doesn't return anything. Any suggestions of how to get a list of People from my Collection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
var people = collection.CollectionEntries.Where( entry => entry.Object is Person )
                                         .Select(entry => (Person)entry.Object)
                                         .ToList();
```

or

```
var people = collection.CollectionEntries.Where( entry => entry.Object is Person )
                                         .Select(entry => entry.Object)
                                         .Cast<Person>()
                                         .ToList();
```

They should both work with your example.

Comment: Ended up using the select method but had to use entry.Object rather than just entry. Thanks for the prompt response!

Comment: Oops yes silly me, i have corrected the answer now. BTW you can use backticks ` to wrap code snippets in comments

Answer (score 2):

Try this:-

```
var people = collection.CollectionEntries.Select( entry => entry.Object).OfType<Person>().ToList();
```

You needed to project the list to get to the `.Object` first and then filter according to the type.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative way of writing this is to use the `let` keyword inside query syntax
(then you can perform just one cast using the `as` keyword, which may be more efficient):

```
var people = 
  (from e in collection.CollectionEntries
   let pers = entry.Object as Person
   where pers != null select pers).ToList();
```